What Makes pgrep Utility Unique Despite ps | grep Availability?
Could someone please explain the purpose of the pgrep utility when it seems like its functionality can be replaced with ps | grep?
P.S. My teacher assigned me this question and asked me to explain why a new utility needed to be created if the same functionality exists in ps | grep. I suspect that 'pgrep' provides us with something that ps | grep does not, but what is it?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the exact error message you get? Edit your question and describe the problem. Copy and paste the error in your question. Read the site help and learn what kind of questions you may ask here.

" then why do you need this utility at all?"  backwards compatibility is mostly the answer to that question.

that is, you want to say that the functionality of this utility can be replaced with 'ps aux | grep'? In general, I was given the task of explaining why to create a whole utility 'pgrep' if you can get the same result using grep with pipelines. –  @Rinzwind

not 100%. pgrep never shows its own id in the results and ps often does.

@Rinzwind, but we can fix that with cut, i mean we can have something specific with 'pgrep' that 'ps aux | grep' can't give for us

This could be a fair question about what more one could do using pgrep instead of ps + grep, however the way it's framed makes it come across as you're holding a grudge against pgrep for some reason, maybe you want to reword at least the last statement, very little is useless, and some utilities are old, yes, but backwards-compatible as well as Rinzwind mentions.

other examples exist like zcat instead of gzip -cd file.gz | cat for example ... It's normal to have multiple utilities doing the same thing (or similar).

There are many. From man pgrep:
-g, --pgroup pgrp,...
      Only  match  processes  in  the  process  group  IDs  listed.   Process  group 0 is
      translated into pgrep's, pkill's, or pidwait's own process group.

-G, --group gid,...
      Only match processes whose real group  ID  is  listed.   Either  the  numerical  or
      symbolical value may be used.
-n, --newest
      Select only the newest (most recently started) of the matching processes.

-o, --oldest
      Select only the oldest (least recently started) of the matching processes.

-O, --older secs
      Select processes older than secs.

-P, --parent ppid,...
      Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed.

-s, --session sid,...
      Only  match  processes  whose  process  session  ID  is  listed.   Session  ID 0 is
      translated into pgrep's, pkill's, or pidwait's own session ID.

-t, --terminal term,...
      Only match processes whose controlling  terminal  is  listed.   The  terminal  name
      should be specified without the "/dev/" prefix.

-u, --euid euid,...
      Only  match  processes  whose effective user ID is listed.  Either the numerical or
      symbolical value may be used.

-U, --uid uid,...
      Only match processes whose real  user  ID  is  listed.   Either  the  numerical  or
      symbolical value may be used.

-v, --inverse
      Negates the matching.  This option is usually used in pgrep's or pidwait's context.
      In pkill's context the short option is disabled to avoid accidental  usage  of  the
      option.

-w, --lightweight
      Shows  all  thread ids instead of pids in pgrep's or pidwait's context.  In pkill's
      context this option is disabled.

-x, --exact
      Only match processes whose names (or command lines  if  -f  is  specified)  exactly
      match the pattern.

-F, --pidfile file
      Read PIDs from file.  This option is more useful for pkill or pidwait than pgrep.

-A, --ignore-ancestors
      Ignore  all ancestors of pgrep, pkill, or pidwait.  For example, this can be useful
      when elevating with sudo or similar tools.

-H, --require-handler
      Only match processes with a userspace signal handler present for the signal  to  be
      sent.

--cgroup name,...
      Match on provided control group (cgroup) v2 name. See cgroups(8)

--ns pid
      Match  processes  that  belong  to  the same namespaces. Required to run as root to
      match processes from other users. See --nslist for how to limit which namespaces to
      match.

--nslist name,...
      Match only the provided namespaces. Available namespaces: ipc, mnt, net, pid, user,
      uts.

Have fun crafting grep expressions to filter the output of ps aux to match the exact behaviour of these options!

Can we get some specific information from pgrep that ps aux | grep will not provide?

@gsagagsa yes, some of the filters listed above do provide information that ps aux | grep cannot provide.

pgrep also provides a convenient method for combining predicates ex. pgrep -u root,steeldriver ssh to match processes owned by root OR steeldriver AND whose names match ssh
